# Using repaint() method properly

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, paintcomponent, repaint

I have a button that when pressed calls a changecolor() method in a different class where some drawing is done. The button listener works fine and I see from some logging that the color was in fact changed but my drawing is not updated. This is my current implementation:

(This method is called when a button is clicked)

```
public void changeWarningLightColor(){
    System.out.println("change color method called");
    if(warningLights.equals(Color.GREEN)){
        warningLights=Color.RED;
        System.out.println(warningLights);
        repaint();  
    }
    else{
        warningLights=Color.GREEN;
        repaint();  
    }
}
```

and my drawing is created in the same file in the above method as follows:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawSomething();
            //draw a bunch of lines
}
```

My question is what is the proper way to call repaint() in order to actually update the drawing? Do I need to somehow call g.repaint() or do something different?

Separate class where the frame is created:

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame {

public MainWindow(){
    JPanel Window = new JPanel(); 
    JPanel LeftSidePanel = new JPanel();
    LeftSidePanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    LeftSidePanel.add(new DrawStatus(),BorderLayout.CENTER); //where the drawing is added

    Window.setLayout(new BoxLayout(Window,0));
    Window.add(LeftSidePanel);

    add(Window);    

}

public static void main(String[] args)  {
    //main method for showing the frame we created with the panels, and circles inside it 
    MainWindow frame = new MainWindow();
    frame.setSize((int) (.75*Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth()),(int) (.75*Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight()));
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setTitle("DVPWS v1.0");
    frame.setResizable(false);

    MenuBar menu = new MenuBar();
    frame.setJMenuBar(menu);
    frame.setVisible(true);


}



}
```

Comment: The `repaint()` method does not actually call the `paintComponent()` method directly, and rightly so. Instead, the `repaint()` method _makes a request_ for the `paintComponent()` to be called. When the UI thread has some "free time", it then calls the method. Is your UI thread working on some other task that may be hanging it up? If so, you might want to move that task to it's own thread. Also, if you're thinking about just calling `paintComponent()` yourself, please don't. You'll end up spamming it and causing more problems than you're solving.

Comment: No my UI thread isnt working on anything else. the app cant do anything besides change colors at this point

Comment: There could potentially be some thread issues if `warningLight` is set from a different thread (and I suppose it is). Try to print out the value of `warningLight` from within the `paintComponent()` method to check whether that is the case.

Comment: Apologies for not including all code. Please see updated code where BorderLayout was set. Note that my program displays everything as expected except for repainting. That is the only problem.

Comment: Probably if you show a runnable example, it will be easier to tell whats going on. At least the panel that's being painted

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Jframe (most likely are) do

```
    yourFrame.repaint();
```

Optionally

```
    yourPanel.repaint();
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to do it from a panel though?

Comment: The way I've always seen it done is from the frame but i guess it goes both ways.

Comment: I've always created a separate panel, done all drawing in there, and than added that to a driver which contains the frame. Breaks it down further.

Comment: @FriarBob Well in a `JFrame`, lots of methods, such as `setLayout()` and `add()` are redirected to the frame's content pane. You aren't actually setting the layout or adding things to the frame itself, but the panel that the frame contains. I believe (but am not sure) that the frame holds the same policy for it's `repaint()` method. If someone knows for sure please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Well the code above works, I always have my frame and panel in isolated classes though that isn't usually recomended.

Comment: You are correct the panel is contained inside the frame.

Comment: @FeatheredOrcian But does the frame redirect the `repaint()` method as well? I know it has it's own `paint()` method separate from the content pane's `paintComponent()` method...

Comment: ez4Nick don't forget to mark the answer as accepted so that others arriving at this post get the correct answer.

Comment: Well Im not 100% sure this solves my issue. It looks to be more complicated then I initially thought. My JFrame and JPAnel that this drawing is in are located in a different class. I just tried to reference the panel from the class where the color change is and I got a NPE. I will have to find a different way of doing this.

Comment: Did you try getGraphics()? It can be tricky getting anything from that method, but if there is already something there I believe it should be fine.

Comment: create an instance of your JFrame in the class that you are using the repaint method in like so:

Comment: OutsideJFrame frame = new OutsideJframe();

frame.repaint();

Comment: I tried that and was had the same issue of the drawing not updating.

Comment: @FriarBob `getGraphics()` is tricky because the frame has to be instantiated and shown before that method stops returning `null`. I'd advise against it if you can avoid it.

Comment: @AndrewG Yes that is what I meant by it being tricky to use. However if the conditions are met it is viable.

Comment: @FriarBob Yeah. Putting it inside some `WindowListener` method would be your best bet of avoiding an NPE.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you could do

```
    public MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();

    mw.repaint();
```

If that doesnt work(i had a similar problem) than your going to have to make an instance of JFrame instead of extending it.

Comment: It seems that if I try to create a new MainWindow object I get a stack overflow error.